Is there a single word (or a short phrase) meaning "to be used both in the UK and in the US"
I'm looking for a word that is the 'opposite' of American/British English.
Is there a word such that

The word X is ???? = The word X is used both in the UK and in the US.

One possibility is region-free, but I don't think it is a proper word for the context. Possibly non-dialectical?
An additional question: is there a word to refer to words/phrases that are used irrespective of region but mean different things?

Note: I just mentioned UK/US since the difference is the most commonly discussed.

You mean for example 'computer' is spelled the same in US or UK spelling but unlike 'optimize' in US which is spelled 'optimise' in UK - you want a word that describes how 'computer' is spelled the same in US or UK?

@BCLC It seems the OP is referring to words rathen than spelling differences: Americans say "apartment", "elevator", "side walk", "candy" etc. etc. While British people will usually say "flat". "lift", "pavement", and "sweets".

If you want to collectively refer to English-speaking regions, “Anglosphere” is available.

Pond-agnostic?

@YosefBaskin  apondal

What about Canada or Ireland? They have their own usages and commonalities, as do India, Australia, the Carribbean, etc. Anglo-American is close but would exclude Scotland, Wales, etc, so name the countries.

@StuartF the list could also  Black Country, Scouse, Mancunian English and so on. Besides, there's the OP's disclaimer Note: I just mentioned UK/US since the difference is the most commonly discussed.

TRANSATLANTIC
Oxford Dictionary of English

concerning countries on both sides of the Atlantic, typically Britain and the US: the transatlantic relationship.

Merriam-Webster

of, relating to, or involving countries on both sides of the Atlantic Ocean and especially the U.S. and Great Britain — transatlantic cooperation

Wiktionary

On, spanning or crossing, or from the other side of the Atlantic Ocean.


The difficulty with transatlantic is (ironically) the same as "cross-pond". In BrE, transatlantic doesn't necessarily mean "on both sides" but rather "on the other side". Transatlantic English is American English, not "Both" English.

@Andrew_Leach Yeah, good comment; transatlantic could mean either “on both sides”, “on the other side”, or even “somewhere in between the two sides” (e.g. a transatlantic accent).  Hopefully the context would remove the ambiguity.

BrE is more likely to use "mid-Atlantic" for "somewhere between the two sides" (eg Loyd Grossman has a mid-Atlantic accent). I don't think we have a word for "on both sides".

We have a similar concept in the Antipodes, where trans-Tasman [sea] means “between/across (both) Australia and New Zealand”.

@AndrewLeach: For me (a Brit) it can happily mean either depending on context: “…our translatlantic friends”, spoken between Brits, clearly means “Americans, but using “a translatlantic word” to mean “accepted on both sides” is also quite clear and natural.

If you wanted to coin a neologism I guess pan-Atlantic is available.

This is probably the best possible answer if someone insists on a single word. But because of the ambiguities, its probably better to use a more expansive phrase such as "in both the U.S. and Britain" or similar unless the context is adequate to clarify.

"Transatlantic" is such a fancy adjective that I would assume a transatlantic word was somehow special. Maybe one that had recently become common in one country after long being popular in the other, like "hoovering up" is starting to be in AmE journalism. It sounds weird to say "'the' is a transatlantic word."

Who would say "translatlantic English"? No one. Unless by that one meant "the other guy" when one is in one place or another but it's not serious.

@nekomatic Pan-Atlantic sounds like it would encompass all the countries that boarder the Atlantic, e.g. Angola, Brazil, Canada, etc.

There is no need for such a word. Unless marked as British or American, it is assumed the word is used in both dialects.
If I wanted to emphasize use both places, I could use “cross-pond.”. Lookimg up “across the pond” gives you an idea of informal use.

I think "cross-pond" or "across the pond" are themselves British usage. In the USA it is rare to hear either, I think, except when used jokingly to refer to something exclusively British. Maybe "trans-Atlantic" fits better on both sides of the "pond". But your point that there is no need for such a word in a dictionary context is well taken.

@Wastrel While I agree that cross-pnd is odd, can't say that I've ever heard it used, would you also say the phrase "on both sides of the pond" is more British? I had always assumed that one worked well on, um, both sides of the pond.

I think calling the Atlantic "the pond" is not really American usage. It's more British. I've heard it used by Americans in a fake British accent to make fun of that. I think that most Americans understand the expression, but wouldn't casually use it.

Calling the Atlantic “the pond” emphasizes the closeness of the two countries.  I’m an American who has long been familiar with this use of “the pond”, but don’t recall whether I’ve ever heard it from a U.S. writer.

@Wastrel I hear this usage of "the pond" quite often in the US.

Americans who have a relationship of some kind to the the UK, do use across the pond. But think of this: the US is huge, the UK is small in comparison. So fewer Americans will be using it, in numbers alone. Anyway, the English-speaking world or Anglophone world.

Calling the Atlantic “the pond” is just typical British understatement, which is so widely recognized that even The Korea Times ran an article about it. I never heard anyone talk about typical American understatement - that one feels more than a bit oxymoronic to me.

I sometimes hear across the pond and I'm in the Midwest. It may technically be rare for Americans but it's not so rare to not be understood or so rare that it's odd to hear someone say it. My guess is that it's rarer here because we have less need to talk about them than they do to talk about us.

There is no such word. You have to say "used in both British and American English", or "used in all varieties of English" if that's the case. Or perhaps "not specific to any particular variety of English." As others have said, words are assumed to have this property by default.

"Global English" would make sense to someone reading the phrase.  It is also known as International English or World English.
This would cover English as it is used all over the world, including the rest of the Commonwealth countries who have their own dialect or uniquenesses.
These phrases crop up in association with simplified English courses often marketed to those who are fluent in another language, but want a non-regionalised common base language.
Examples (no connection)

https://www.twinkl.co.nz/teaching-wiki/global-english
https://www.vaia.com/en-us/explanations/english/global-english/

To be Global English the example would avoid idioms and contractions, both of which can trip up new speakers.

The trouble is that 'global English' is a term already in use, with different meanings. According to Wikipedia, one usage is, as you say,  the set of all different varieties of the English language actually in use (the term ... 'may acknowledge the diversity and varieties of English spoken throughout the world'). Idioms and all.  Which conflicts starkly  with OP's request for a term describing the intersection (overlap) set not the union set.

@EdwinAshworth you make a good point - this is a question about Set Theory masquerading as a question about language.

global English is some made up term that corresponds to nothing at all.

@Lambie all language is "made up"

@Fe2O3 Onomatopoeic words aim to evoke the sounds they're describing, but even so, they're usually more human invention than a reproduction of nature. For instance, the exact same sound is represented as "ngok" in Indonesian, "grrr" in Spanish, and "chrum" in Polish, and even though all of those are onomatopoeic formations I doubt many people unfamiliar with those languages would be able to pick the English equivalent. They're not "made up" in the sense of being completely arbitrary, but then neither are terms like "global English".

I make stuff up as I go along however I do not make up my languages! [joke]

@Fe2O3 I will see your "boing" and raise you a "tch tch tch" :-)

Case 1. Political
Hey sundowner, I'm not sure if you mean something political, but if ever there's always west, western world or occident. From Wikipedia:

The Western world, also known as the West, primarily refers to various nations and states in the regions of Australasia, Western Europe, and Northern America; with some debate as to whether those in Eastern Europe and Latin America[c] also constitute the West. The Western world likewise is called the Occident (from Latin occidens 'setting down, sunset, west') in contrast to the Eastern world known as the Orient (from Latin oriens 'origin, sunrise, east').

or

"Occident" is a term for the West, traditionally comprising anything that belongs to the Western world. It is the antonym of the term Orient, referring to the Eastern world. In English, it has largely fallen into disuse. The term "occidental" is often used to describe objects from the Occident but can be considered an outdated term by some. The term originated with geographical divisions mirroring the cultural divide between the Greek East and the Latin West, and the political divide between the Western and Eastern Roman Empires.

So to say some aspect of politics or culture is the same whether in the US or in the UK, like 'Americans love democracy' and 'The British love democracy', I'd say 'The West loves democracy.'
Case 2a. Spelling
If you mean for example 'computer' is spelled the same in US or UK spelling but unlike 'optimize' (US) it is spelled 'optimise' in the UK and you want a word to describe how 'computer' is spelled the same in the US or the UK, then I don't think there's a word for that.
You can try 'standard' if the context is clearly about spelling differences. If I wanted to talk about a list of words, each might differ in US/UK spelling, then I'd try as follows:
List US spelling of words

Computer
Optimize
Banana
Jacket
Aluminum
Spelled

And then indicate UK spelling differences like
'The following words are spelt the same in UK spelling, unless otherwise indicated'

Computer
Optimize - UK: Optimise
Banana
Jacket
Aluminum - UK: Aluminium
Spelled - UK: Spelt

Case 2b. Vocabulary
List US terminology of words

Computer
Apartment
Banana
Jacket
Cracker
Elevator

And then indicate UK terminology differences like
'The following words also used by the British, unless otherwise indicated'
or
'The following words are the same throughout Western English, unless otherwise indicated'

Computer
Apartment - UK: Flat
Banana
Jacket
Cracker - UK: Biscuit
Elevator - UK: Lift


(2) The -ise/-ize split is far from being UK vs US usage. For instance, Oxford University Press recommends realize etc (this is even called 'Oxford style and is preferred in OED) whereas the Oxford University style guide recommends realise etc. /  (6) These Google 1-grams indicate that 'spelled' seems more common than 'spelt' even in the UK nowadays (and remember that the nounal homonym 'spelt' bumps up the figures for this variant). // But 'occidental' to mean ...

'used in the US and UK alike' is far too woolly, and would confuse if used in linguistics without a stipulative definition.

For the spelling, the difference I was thinking could include that too, but as put in the comment, I was more thinking about difference in vocabulary. Re: political, isn't it too narrow to call the US and the UK alone "the West"? I thought when you say "the West", it includes at least some continental western countries.

@sundowner Politics: Of course West is more than just US & UK. At the very least 'western europe' and 'north america' are the top regions in the economist democracy index. Spelling/vocabulary: Oh terminology that's common in the west whether US or UK like 'computer' is the same but cracker vs biscuit isn't ? I guess I'd the say the same. I'll edit.

cracker (US) and cracker (UK) but it's normally cookie (US) and biscuit (UK), biscuit (US) and scone (UK)? No?

Standard English implies this:
Merriam-Webster

The English that with respect to spelling, grammar, pronunciation, and
vocabulary is substantially uniform though not devoid of regional
differences, that is well established by usage in the formal and
informal speech and writing of the educated, and that is widely
recognized as acceptable wherever English is spoken and understood


That is not what "Standard English" means.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Meriam-Webster begs to differ:  Standar English can mean "the English that with respect to spelling, grammar, pronunciation, and vocabulary is substantially uniform though not devoid of regional differences ... and that is widely recognized as acceptable wherever English is spoken."  I'd italicise 'vocabulary ... widely recognized'.     And yes, I'm aware 'Standard English' is also if not primarily a relative term implying socio-linguistic judgment between core and periphery.

But would you call US/UK-only words non-standard?

How about:

Unicontinental

as in uniting the different continents who speak the language in that context.
Ofc: if it also includes Australia, New Zealand, ...
Otherwise maybe:

Euramerica

or even

Euram

